# .animate jquery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, jquery-animate

I am making a drop down menu that comes up when a button is hovered over and then is suppose to stay open when your mouse is hovering over the menu items to be clicked on.

can anyone help me?
Thank you so much.

```
$('document').ready(function(){

// Bring up the dropdown menus - this part works

    $("#dropdownButton").hover(
        function() { 
            $(".dropdownDiv").filter(':not(:animated)').stop().animate({ height: '120px'}, 120).show(120) },
        function() { 
            $(".dropdownDiv").filter(':not(:animated)').stop().animate({ height:0}, 120).hide(120) }
    );

//Keep dropdown visible - this doesn't stop the menu from disappearing

    $(".dropdownDiv").hover(
        function() {
            $(".dropdownDiv").filter(':not(:animated)').stop().animate({ height: '120px'}, 120).show(120) },
        function() { 
            $(".dropdownDiv").filter(':not(:animated)').stop().animate({ height:0}, 120).hide(120) }
    );
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="topNav">
    <a href="Courses-and-Dates/" title="Courses &amp; Dates">Courses &amp; Dates</a>
    <a id="dropdownButton" href="Tracks-and-Cars/" title="Tracks &amp; Cars">Tracks &amp; Cars</a>
    <a href="Corporate/" title="Corporate">Corporate</a>
    <a href="Celebrity-Race/" title="Celebrity Race">Celebrity Race</a>
    <a href="About-Us/" title="About Us">About</a>
    <a href="Contact-Us/" title="Contact Us">Contact</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdownMainCont">
    <div class="dropdownMainContainer">
        <div class="dropdownDiv">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS

```
.dropdownMainCont{
    position:absolute;
    top:170px;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
.dropdownMainContainer{
    width:1024px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.dropdownDiv{
    background:#C00;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    height:0;/*auto*/
    width:180px;
    padding:10px;
    left:210px;
    float:left;
    display:none;
    z-index:1500;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using pure CSS for this?

Comment: Could you post your HTML/CSS markup? I'm guessing this is an issue with your `$('#dropdownDiv')` element not being contained within the `$('dropdownButton')` element. Also, you should look into jQuery's `.slideToggle()` method. It would simplify your code a lot.

Comment: I added the HTML and CSS to my original post